# click and drag SVG, extend to touch support

Tags: javascript, events, svg, touch

I have an SVG image created inline in the HTML document. I am trying to write a minimal amount of javascript to allow the image to be panned and zoomed. I have the behavior exactly as I want for mouse interactions but am struggling to get the same behavior with touch.

The functions to move the item are

```
    startMove: function (evt) {
    this.move = true;
    this.x1 = evt.clientX;
    this.y1 = evt.clientY;
    var xScale = this.view[2]/this.svgElement.offsetWidth;
    var yScale = this.view[3]/this.svgElement.offsetHeight;
    this.scale = (yScale > xScale) ? yScale : xScale;
},
moveIt: function (evt) {
    if (this.move) {
        var dx = evt.clientX - this.x1;
        var dy = evt.clientY - this.y1;
        this.x1 = evt.clientX;
        this.y1 = evt.clientY;
        evt.ctrlKey ? this.zoom(Math.pow(2,-dy/100)) : this.pan(this.scale*dx, this.scale*dy);
    }
},
endMove: function (evt) {
    this.move = false
}
```

I attach the functions to event handlers in svgManoeuvre.init() as follows
transformGroup is the svg group to which the transform matrix is applied to move the element.

This code works with mouse events but not touch events, what am I missing. I thought there would be a simple analogue between events for the panning interaction.

So far the only touch device I have tried this on is a windows phone.
View the webpage here

http://www.londonlayout.co.uk/nav

```
this.transformGroup.addEventListener('mousedown',function (evt){
    svgManoeuvre.startMove(evt);
    },false);
    this.transformGroup.addEventListener('mousemove',function (evt){
    svgManoeuvre.moveIt(evt);
    },false); 
    this.transformGroup.addEventListener('mouseup',function (evt){
    svgManoeuvre.endMove(evt);
    },false); 
    this.transformGroup.addEventListener('touchstart',function (evt){
    svgManoeuvre.startMove(evt);
    },false);
    this.transformGroup.addEventListener('touchmove',function (evt){
    svgManoeuvre.moveIt(evt);
    },false); 
    this.transformGroup.addEventListener('touchend',function (evt){
    svgManoeuvre.endMove(evt);
    },false);
```

Comment: Webpage isn't working there (comes up with a 404)

Comment: ahh thanks ian. I move it to type less in my phone just updating question now